# comparar elementos y mostrar alerta o ejecutar funcion en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy practicando javascript y creando un gestor de listas de tareas.

tengo mi campo input, que al presionar el botón o dar enter pasa el value del input a una lista de tareas más abajo. Lo que quiero y no se como hacer, es: que al dar enter o click en el botón compare lo que está en el value del input con los elementos que ya están en la lista y si ya existe un elemento con la misma cadena de texto me envie una alerta.

Muchas gracias :)

[image: captura]

```js
        //variables
        var lista = document.getElementById("lista"),
        tareaInput = document.getElementById("tareaInput"),
        btnNuevaTarea = document.getElementById("btn-agregar");

        //funciones
        var agregarTarea = function(){
            var tarea = tareaInput.value,
                nuevaTarea = document.createElement("li"),
                enlace = document.createElement("a"),
                contenido = document.createTextNode(tarea);

        if (tarea === "") {
            tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "agrega una tarea valida");
            tareaInput.className = "error";
            document.getElementById("contenedor_principal").classList.add("bg_red");
            return false;
        }

        //funcion revisar repetidos
      
     
        //agregamos el contenido a los enlaces
        enlace.appendChild(contenido);
        //le establecemos un atributo  href
        enlace.setAttribute("href", "#");

        //agregar enlace a la nueva tarea que es un elemento LI
        //ponemos elemento a dentro de li
        nuevaTarea.appendChild(enlace);
        //agregamos nueva tarea a la lista
        lista.appendChild(nuevaTarea);

        //limpiar input al click al boton
        tareaInput.value = "";

    //ciclo eventos borrando elementos de la lista
    for (var i = 0; i <= lista.children.length -1 ; i++)
{
    lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
}

        
    };

    var comprobarInput = function() {
 tareaInput.className= "";
 tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "agrega tu tarea");
 document.getElementById("contenedor_principal").classList.remove("bg_red");
    };
   
    var eliminarTarea = function (){
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    
    };
  
        //eventos
        //agregar tarea
        
        //agregar nueva tarea al hacer click al botón, o al presionar la tecla enter
        btnNuevaTarea.addEventListener("click", agregarTarea);
        addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
                agregarTarea();
            }
        });

  
        //comprobar input
        tareaInput.addEventListener("click", comprobarInput);


        //ciclo eventos borrando elementos de la lista
        for (var i = 0; i <= lista.children.length -1 ; i++)
        {
            //recorrer la lista desde el cero
            lista.children [i].addEventListener("click", eliminarTarea);
        }
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
 background: #FAFAFA;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
 
.wrap {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 90%;
}
 
.principal {
 background: #198CFF;
 border-top: 20px solid #1066BB;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 50px 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 
.principal .formulario {
 color: #212121;
 text-align: center;
}
 
.principal .formulario input[type=text] {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
 
.principal .formulario input[type=text].error {
 color: #F86969!important;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 transition:  all .3s ease-out;
}
 
.principal .formulario .boton {
 background: none;
 border: 1px solid #Fff;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 15px;
}
 
.principal .formulario .boton:hover {
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
 
/* - Tareas - */
.tareas .lista {
 list-style: none;
}
 
.tareas .lista li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6;
}
 
.tareas .lista li a {
 color: #212121;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.tareas .lista li a:hover {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

.bg_red {
 background:#F86969;
 border-top: 20px solid #F86969;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 transition:  all .3s ease-out;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css">
 <title>Lista de Tareas</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="principal" id="contenedor_principal">
  <div class="wrap">
   <form class="formulario" action="">
    <input type="text" id="tareaInput"  placeholder="Agrega tu tarea" autofocus>
    <input type="button" class="boton" id="btn-agregar" value="Agregar Tarea">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="tareas">
  <div class="wrap">
   <ul class="lista" id="lista">
 
   </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
    


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un array con el contenido de tu lista y luego chequear si el elemento ya existe en el array antes de agregarlo.  Algo asi:

```js
//variables
        var lista = document.getElementById("lista"),
        tareaInput = document.getElementById("tareaInput"),
        btnNuevaTarea = document.getElementById("btn-agregar");
        var alista = [];

        //funciones
        var agregarTarea = function(){
            var tarea = tareaInput.value,
                nuevaTarea = document.createElement("li"),
                enlace = document.createElement("a"),
                contenido = document.createTextNode(tarea);

        if (tarea === "") {
            tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "agrega una tarea valida");
            tareaInput.className = "error";
            document.getElementById("contenedor_principal").classList.add("bg_red");
            return false;
        }

        //funcion revisar repetidos        
        if (alista.indexOf(tarea) == -1) {
           alista.push(tarea);
        //agregamos el contenido a los enlaces
            enlace.appendChild(contenido);
            //le establecemos un atributo  href
            enlace.setAttribute("href", "#");

            //agregar enlace a la nueva tarea que es un elemento LI
            //ponemos elemento a dentro de li
            nuevaTarea.appendChild(enlace);
            //agregamos nueva tarea a la lista
            lista.appendChild(nuevaTarea);

            //limpiar input al click al boton
            tareaInput.value = "";

          //ciclo eventos borrando elementos de la lista
          for (var i = 0; i <= lista.children.length -1 ; i++)
          {
              lista.children[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
              });
          }
        } else {
          alert("El elemento ya existe");
        }

        
    };

    var comprobarInput = function() {
 tareaInput.className= "";
 tareaInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "agrega tu tarea");
 document.getElementById("contenedor_principal").classList.remove("bg_red");
    };
   
    var eliminarTarea = function (){
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    
    };
  
        //eventos
        //agregar tarea
        
        //agregar nueva tarea al hacer click al botón, o al presionar la tecla enter
        btnNuevaTarea.addEventListener("click", agregarTarea);
        addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter
                agregarTarea();
            }
        });

  
        //comprobar input
        tareaInput.addEventListener("click", comprobarInput);


        //ciclo eventos borrando elementos de la lista
        for (var i = 0; i <= lista.children.length -1 ; i++)
        {
            //recorrer la lista desde el cero
            lista.children [i].addEventListener("click", eliminarTarea);
        }
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
body {
 background: #FAFAFA;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
 
.wrap {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 90%;
}
 
.principal {
 background: #198CFF;
 border-top: 20px solid #1066BB;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 50px 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 
.principal .formulario {
 color: #212121;
 text-align: center;
}
 
.principal .formulario input[type=text] {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
 
.principal .formulario input[type=text].error {
 color: #F86969!important;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 transition:  all .3s ease-out;
}
 
.principal .formulario .boton {
 background: none;
 border: 1px solid #Fff;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 15px;
}
 
.principal .formulario .boton:hover {
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}
 
/* - Tareas - */
.tareas .lista {
 list-style: none;
}
 
.tareas .lista li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6;
}
 
.tareas .lista li a {
 color: #212121;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
 
.tareas .lista li a:hover {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

.bg_red {
 background:#F86969;
 border-top: 20px solid #F86969;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:  all .3s ease-out;
 transition:  all .3s ease-out;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css">
 <title>Lista de Tareas</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="principal" id="contenedor_principal">
  <div class="wrap">
   <form class="formulario" action="">
    <input type="text" id="tareaInput"  placeholder="Agrega tu tarea" autofocus>
    <input type="button" class="boton" id="btn-agregar" value="Agregar Tarea">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="tareas">
  <div class="wrap">
   <ul class="lista" id="lista">
 
   </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
    


</body>
</html>
```